# How to change a live object's isinstance() behavior?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, metaclass

I want to change the behavior of `isinstance` for a live python object.

One solution is to create a simple wrapper like the following, but I do not like it:

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.inner_self = obj

lizard = ['head', 'nose', 'tail']
wlizard = Widget(lizard)
assert(isinstance(wlizard, Widget)) # no assertion error thrown
```

What I don't like about this particular wrapper, is that we must extract the `lizard` from `wlizard` before we can use the `lizard` again

```
try:
    wlizard[0]
except:
    print('sorry, wlizard doesn\'t behave like a lizard')

lizard = wlizard.inner_self
print(lizard[0]) # works fine
```

What I really want is for `wlizard` to behave exactly like lizard except that `isinstance` returns `True` for `wlizard` and it returns false for `lizard`.

The following sort-of works, but has some drawbacks:

```
class Widget:
    pass

def MakeAWidget(obj):

    class Blah(type(obj), Widget):
        pass
        # inherits type(obj)'s __init__ method

    wobj = Blah(obj)  # calls type(obj)'s copy constructor
    return wobj
```

One problem is that this only works if `type(obj)`'s `__init__()` method takes in more than just `self`; in particular, that `__init__` can take in an instance of `type(obj)`, and when it does, it copies the attributes of `obj` into `self`. I would like something that works even if `obj` does not have a copy constructor. Something like the following might be possible to force the existence of a copy-constructor:

```
import copy
class Blah(type(obj), Widget):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(args[0], type(obj)):
            self = copy.deepcopy(args[0])
            return self
        return super(type(self), self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, I would rather not copy the object, only modify it in-place.
Something like the following might be possible, but I am not sure what `__BLAH__` would be:

```
obj = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana']
assert(not isinstance(obj, Widget)) # no error thrown    
obj.__BLAH__.append('Widget')
assert(isinstance(obj, Widget))  # no error thrown
```

Comment: This sounds like you've picked a bad solution to some underlying problem that would be better solved without doing this. Why are you trying to change your objects in this way? Why do you care about how your objects respond to `isinstance`, rather than the behavior they support?

Comment: What kind of Python object is `lizard`?

Comment: @user2357112 I create a wrapper which allows one to access an object's `__getitem__` method through `__getattribute__`. `wrap_obj.key == obj[key]` However, I want to know if the value returned came from `__getitem__` or was an attribute of `obj`. One solution seems to be to call `isinstance` on the returned value to see what it is.

Comment: @Blender In my example, `lizard` is a `list`. However, in the actual application, we do not know what `lizard` will be a priori. The solution needs to be general enough to handle most types of objects.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone: Since you have control over the underlying class, what exact problem are you trying to solve? This seems like a bad approach.

Comment: We do not have access to the underlying/warapped object. the object is returned by a different object's `__getattribute__` method. We need to test whether this item has been flagged in someway. The original attribute isn't of a class which supports flagging

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone: I meant over `Widget` and whatever class is returning `lizard`. Usually you write hacks like this to monkey-patch libraries or get them to execute code in ways that you need them to. When you have this much control, there isn't a good reason to do things like this. Can you describe what you're trying to do in general, not this specific problem with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I think does what you want. The `wrap()` function dynamically creates a class which is derived from the class of the `obj` argument passed to it, and then returns an instance of that class created from it. This assumes the class of `obj` supports copy construction (initialization from an instance of the same — or derived — class).

```
def wrap(obj):
    class MetaClass(type):
        def __new__(mcls, classname, bases, classdict):
            wrapped_classname = '_%s_%s' % ('Wrapped', type(obj).__name__)
            return type.__new__(mcls, wrapped_classname, (type(obj),)+bases, classdict)

    class Wrapped(metaclass=MetaClass):
        pass

    return Wrapped(obj)

lizard = ['head', 'nose', 'tail']
wlizard = wrap(lizard)
print(type(wlizard).__name__)     # -> _Wrapped_list
print(isinstance(wlizard, list))  # -> True

try:
    wlizard[0]
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    print("sorry, wlizard doesn't behave like lizard")
else:
    print('wlizard[0] worked')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you want. This solution allows you to decorate any object so that the wrapper instance gets all the methods and attributes of the wrapped one.

This is a metaclass of the wrapper:

```
class WrapperMeta(type):
    @classmethod
    def __new_getattr(mcs, method, inst):
        if method is None:
            method = object.__getattribute__

        def new_method(self, key):
            try:
                return method(self, key)
            except AttributeError:
                return method(inst.wrappee.fget(self), key)
        return new_method

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, kwargs):
        if not bases:
            bases = (object,)
        if len(bases) != 1:
            raise TypeError("Wrapper can wrap only one class")
        if type(kwargs.get("wrappee")) != property:
            raise AttributeError("wrapper class must have a \"wrappee\" property")

        inst = type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, kwargs)
        inst.__getattribute__ = mcs.__new_getattr(inst.__getattribute__, inst)
        return inst
```

It requires a wrapper to have exactly one parent class (the one you want to wrap), to have "wrappee" property and overrides **__getattribute__** in a way you need.

This is a base class:

```
class VeryImportantClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def very_important_function(self, n):
        return n + self.a
```

This is a wrapper class:

```
class Wrapper(VeryImportantClass, metaclass=WrapperMeta):
    def __init__(self, vii):
        self._vii = vii

    @property
    def wrappee(self):
        return self._vii

    def very_important_addition(self, n):
        return n - self.a * 4
```

And that is the result:

```
vii = VeryImportantClass()
vii = Wrapper(vii)
print(vii.very_important_function(5))  # 6
print(vii.very_important_addition(1))  # -3
print(isinstance(vii, VeryImportantClass))  # True
```